# How do I debug Gallina (Coq) code?

Tags: coq

I have some complex functional code in Gallina that I run under Coq. From time to time bugs emerge and I need to debug the code. Is there a way to debug the code from Coq, or am I stuck with doing everything by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin which allows to do prints from gallina functions:

https://github.com/coq-community/reduction-effects

I find this quite effective for debugging gallina code.